# How to know which Seeds require Pollination Partners ?

Tags: seeds, planting

Being new to Gardening , I came across this concept of Pollination Partners , and that some seeds require a partner when the seed is planted.

Can someone tell me , why this is needed and what seeds require these ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly the seeds which need pollination partners, but the flowers on the plant itself if you require fruit from it. Some plants, like some Malus (apple) varieties and Pyrus (pear varieties) are not self fertile, so they can't pollinate/fertilize their own flowers. Unfertilized flowers means no fruits will form, so its usual to plant two different varieties that will cross pollinate each other, or use a different plant which flowers at the same time (crab apple in the case of apples, for instance). Without pollination, fertlization of the flowers doesn't happen.

In some plants, they are self fertile, but better results and larger crops are achieved by planting with an appropriate pollination partner (lychee for instance). This partner is usually a plant of the same type or family which happens to flower at the same time.

If you decide you want to grow fruits, then its best to look them up and check whether they need another plant for cross pollination - apples and pears, for instance, have numbered pollination groups, and there are lists of recommended varieties to plant together.

If your plant doesn't produce fruit, or you're not growing it for that purpose, then the pollination partner thing is irrelevent.